# given full name in a sentence, is there a way to match anything besides a sentence with that full name?

Tags: regex

Below is the regular expression I came up with

it is used to match any first name + last name except a given one

(first) (last) went to college

> ^(?!(tom tom))([A-Za-z'$]+ [A-Za-z'$]+) went to college

https://regex101.com/r/Zsc9W5/1

tom tom went to college (will not match)

which is what I am looking for

when using apostrophes however

'tom tom (matches)
to'm tom (matches)
tom to'm (matches)
tom tom' (doesn't match)
tom tom's (doesn't match)

the last 2 are supposed to match

what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last 2 will not match due to the negative lookahead at the start which asserts that what is on the right is not tom tom. That does not succeed for the last 2 examples where it starts with tom tom.

One way could be to add after the negative lookahead a negated character class that it should not match `[^A-Za-z'$]` what you would allow to match in the name:

```
^(?!tom tom[^A-Za-z'$])([A-Za-z'$]+ [A-Za-z'$]+) went to college
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fh7G5L/1)

Comment: thanks for your answer, your explanation solved my problem and other expressions that I had issues with.